# oData filter on array element

Tags: c#, rest, odata

I wanted to know if it was possible to filter on a specific array element.
I know that it is possible to filter on nested properties and to apply any/all functions on collections, but didn't find any documentation on how to filter on specific index on collection.
As an example (expressed in Linq):

> data.Where(d => d.Proposals[0].Growth.Value == 0.05m)

I'm expecting a syntax like:

> $filter=Proposals(0)/Growth/Value eq 0.05M

Answer (score 2):

OData is based on the Entity Data Model, which does not support ordered collections (arrays). So there is no built-in syntax for filtering by position.

If your goal is to filter against a default `Growth/Value` using a client-supplied value, you can achieve that with an OData function. Declare the function in your Web API config.

```
// builder is an instance of ODataConventionModelBuilder
var defaultGrowthValueFunction = builder.EntityType<Zebra>().Collection.Function("WhereGrowthEquals");
defaultGrowthValueFunction.Parameter<decimal>("value");
defaultGrowthValueFunction.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Zebra>("Zebras");
```

The function is named `WhereGrowthEquals` and it is bound to the `Zebras` entity set. (I've invented an entity type named `Zebra` to host the `Proposals` array from your example above.)

Now define the function in the `ZebrasController`. (For testing, I defined a static list of `Zebra` instances named `AllZebras`.)

```
public class ZebrasController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("Zebras/Default.WhereGrowthEquals(value={value})")]
    public IHttpActionResult WhereGrowthEquals(decimal value)
    {
        return this.Ok(AllZebras.Where(z => z.Proposals[0].Growth.Value == value));
    }
}
```

Note that the bound function is namespace-qualified in the ODataRoute attribute. (`Default` is the default namespace name.)

Finally, invoke the function from the client as follows.

```
GET http://hostname/Zebras/Default.WhereGrowthEquals(value=0.05)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Actually I need to express the filter request in a generic way, I can't implement specific filtering on the server side. I mean the requests are to be generated by a client grid depending on the shown columns and those columns are a projection of complex objects (including arrays). I could have another columns referencing a path like Proposals[1].AnotherArray[2].Amount.Value. So, I'm looking for a standard and generic syntaxt to express that path in OData query.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm curious as to how you are modeling the arrays. What does your $metadata doc look like?